# OrientDB - Synchronize local db with remote db

Tags: synchronization, orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

I'm investigating OrientDB for a project in which I have many client applications that need a local graph db (it has to be local for enabling offline work), but they also need to sync their local db to a shared db server for backup and sharing with other clients when they're online.

I see from the OrientDB documentation many different configuration options (Server, embedded server, local, distributed, etc.), but I can't understand if there's an easy way to do what I need, without me having to manage merging and conflict resolution..

Is there a simple solution for what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrientDB hasn't been designed to work offline and then synchronize the database with another one. For this use case you should implement a layer that keeps track of all the changes (through a [Hook](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Hook)) and then merge the result.